# Angular4 : How retrieving the n-2 url

Tags: angular

The url /getEmployees will launch EmployeesComponent which displays the list of employees.

When I click on an employee, the url getEmployee/N, EmployeeComponent is launched,
So I wish I could retrieve the url /getEmployees after I have validated the employee.

Is it possible and how?

Comment: Are you asking for how to get the actual URL? Or how to navigate back to that URL?

Comment: Back, because when I am in EmployeeComponent I want to retrieve /getEmployees wich is the url before the url /getEmployee/4. But location.back() is not the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate back using `RouterLink` as well:

```
<div class='panel-footer'>
    <a class='btn btn-default' routerLink="/getEmployees" >
        <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left'></i> Back
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are just learning Angular, you may want to consider working through a tutorial such as Tour of Heroes here: https://angular.io/tutorial Or a course such as this one: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-2-getting-started-update (you can sign up for a free week if you are not a member)

Comment: Thank you Deborah, but it was an example. Of course I want to generalize, I want in such a situation retrieve the n-x url ( n= the current situation and x the previous urls)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have founded is to use a service wich store the url, here only one url but it could be an array.
SharedService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

  private urlOrigin: string;
  public setUrlOrigin(url: string) :void {this.urlOrigin=url;}
  public getUrlOrigin() {
    let url: string = this.urlOrigin;
    if (url === '')
      url = '/home';
    this.urlOrigin = ''; // remove the url after using
    return url;
  }
  constructor() { }
}
```

EmployeeComponent

```
validateEmployee() {
        this.employeeService.updateEmployee(this.employee).
          subscribe(() => {
            let urlOrigin: string = this.sharedService.getUrlOrigin();
            this.router.navigate([urlOrigin]);
          }),
          error => {
            this.error = error.message;
          };
      }
}
```